# What's the best practice for CoffeeScript + npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, coffeescript

I've been developing Node apps and packages for a while, and have always written in CoffeeScript.

To use npm, I generally do a local install of `coffee-script`, then set a script within `package.json` to run the app, as such:

`"start": "coffee app.coffee"`

Is this the best practice?  I understand that there is an alternative of providing `coffee-script` as a dev dependency, then having a prepublish script to compile coffee -> JS.

Comment: You mean in terms of publishing to NPM? You should ship JS, not CS (or TS or whatever else).

Comment: Right; code should always be shipped as JS.  So, not in terms of publishing, but more so during development.

I'm wondering if it's best to have a start vs prepublish script.  With start, coffee is available to run .coffee files directly, whereas prepublish will preprocess coffee -> JS, then have node run as usual with JS files.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is to have the coffeescript in a `src/` directory and compile it to a `lib/` directory.

My `.gitignore` contains a `lib/` line and my `.npmignore` file contains a single line with `src/`.  Thus the source does not get published to npm and the javascript does not get published to Github.

My `package.json` file contains the following:

```
  "main": "lib/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "coffee -c -w -o lib src &",
    "compile": "coffee -c -o lib src",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run-script compile"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "coffeescript": "^2.3.2"
  }
```

So while I'm working, I run `npm watch` to keep the javascript files up to date.  But before publishing, it ensures that the javascript files are up to date.